# call web parser from GUI python

Tags: python, parsing, user-interface, pyqt, beautifulsoup

I'm teaching myself object oriented programming in python. I'm using a basic GUI and a simple web parser - both of which are in separate class files. My goal is to call the web parser from the GUI.

My web parser class just downloads a page and stores it as a list. I want a simple printout of the web page when I push a button on my GUI. Except I'm running into problems. When I click the button it states that my 'parser' name is not defined. I'm starting to get a little confused. If someone could me figure this out that would be great. Thanks.

My web parser:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self, url):    
        self.url = url
        self.contents  = ''

   def download_page(self):

        #open the page
        page=urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

        page_find=soup.findAll('td')

        #lists for storing page data 
        page_list = []

        #Store HTML table data into list
        for page_data in page_find:
            page_list.append(page_data.string)

        return page_list



 if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "http://www.any_url"
    Parser = Parser(url)
    print Parser.download_page()
```

My GUI class is below:

```
class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    #Made changes here
    self.url = url
    self.parser = Parser(url)
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):      

    parse_list = []    

    btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Button 1", self)
    btn1.move(30, 50)

    btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)            
    self.statusBar()

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
    self.show()



 #supposed to call web parser when button is pressed   
def buttonClicked(self):

    parse_list = parser.download_page()
    print parse_list
    sender = self.sender()
    self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

Comment: looks like a scope problem, `parser` is contained within `initUI()`. It's gone by the time you call `buttonClicked()`.

Comment: @RedAlert I moved parser = Parser(object) into buttonClicked() but got the error: TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'object'

Comment: why are you passing in `object`? What's the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
parse_list = parser.download_page
```

should be

```
parse_list = parser.download_page()
```

The parentheses tells Python to call the method. Without the parentheses, `parser.download_page` refers to the method object itself. Functions are [first-class objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen#Functions) in Python.

---

To fix the `NameError` problem, make `parser` an instance attribute in `initUI`:

```
self.parser = Parser(url)
```

and then reference it with

```
parse_list = self.parser.download_page()
```

in `buttonClicked`. (And, obviously, you need to define `url`.)

Comment: Made the change but still get the same error: global name 'parser' is not defined

Comment: Made the changes above but now I get: global name 'url' is not defined. I did it in the constructor. I guess I did it incorrectly somehow.

Comment: Just a follow up. Do you have an answer for me?

Comment: @dave In `Example.__init__` you have `self.url = url`, but `url` is neither a local nor a global. The `url` should be a string ("http://...") or be obtained from somewhere (text field, dialog box, config file, initialization parameter, etc).

Comment: @Schollii Thanks. But I found the solution elsewhere. Never the less, this thread helped.

Comment: @Schollii You are correct. For some reason, I didn't notice it. Apologies. I deleted my answer.